# Get a path to a file from Node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have an application, where structure looks like this:

```
.
├── index.js
├── unix
│   ├── index.js
└── win32
    ├── foo.exe
    └── index.js
```

`win32/index.js` was accessing `foo.exe` like this:

```
let command = path.join(__dirname, "foo.exe") + ' -some-arguments';
exec(command);
```

But now using Webpack I compile my application into one bundle.js and put that `foo.exe` next to it:

```
.
├── foo.exe
└── bundle.js
```

And now `path.join(__dirname, "foo.exe")` doesn't work anymore. It doesn't find the `foo.exe`. I've changed it to

```
  let command = path.resolve(
    "node_modules/my-library/dist",
    "foo.exe"
  );
```

And it works fine but looks like there is a better way to do it.

**UPD:**

my Webpack config file:

```
const path = require("path");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./src",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    libraryTarget: "umd"
  },
  plugins: [new CopyPlugin([{ from: "./src/win32/foo.exe" }])],
  target: "node"
};
```

Comment: IIRC, Webpack is able to changes the paths if you use `__dirname`. Maybe this is an issue in your webpack config ?

Comment: Hi! Maybe, I am not that experienced with Webpack. I have added my config file to the question

Comment: Thank you for adding the config. I wrote an anwser, you just need to add a property to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have `__dirname` behave the usual way, and not being it changed (mocked) by Webpack, you have to add a property in your Webpack config :

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
  }
};
```

[Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node__dirname)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. But documentation says it should be `boolean` or `"mock"`, so please update the answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these node config in your webpack. So you can use `__dirname` after you built your code with webpack

```
  node: {
      __dirname: false,
    },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tien, I really appreciate that, but Seblor was first